# Java code to get service start time

Tags: java, windows, service, wmi

Can anyone help me Java code to get Windows Service start time. Like how we get using Process Explorer.

Screenshots for enabling the service start time using Process Explorer

[image]

Comment: You can look into JNA.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly Windows-specific, so there is nothing built in to Java or its libraries for this.  One possible approach is to use two external commands, `sc` and `wmic` to extract this information.

Use `sc` to get the process ID of the service you're interested in, for example for service W32Time:

```
C:\>sc queryex W32Time

SERVICE_NAME: W32Time
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
        PID                : 1072
        FLAGS              :
```

Parse out the `PID` value (1072) and then do

```
C:\Users\jim>wmic process where processid="1072"
Caption      CommandLine  CreationClassName  CreationDate               CSCreationClassName   CSName  Description  Execu
tablePath  ExecutionState  Handle  HandleCount  InstallDate  KernelModeTime  MaximumWorkingSetSize  MinimumWorkingSetSiz
e  Name         OSCreationClassName    OSName                                                                     OtherO
perationCount  OtherTransferCount  PageFaults  PageFileUsage  ParentProcessId  PeakPageFileUsage  PeakVirtualSize  PeakW
orkingSetSize  Priority  PrivatePageCount  ProcessId  QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage  QuotaPagedPoolUsage  QuotaPeakNonPagedPool
Usage  QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage  ReadOperationCount  ReadTransferCount  SessionId  Status  TerminationDate  ThreadCount
UserModeTime  VirtualSize  WindowsVersion  WorkingSetSize  WriteOperationCount  WriteTransferCount
svchost.exe               Win32_Process      20160709170336.990827-420  Win32_ComputerSystem  HOME    svchost.exe
                           1072    765                       21060135
   svchost.exe  Win32_OperatingSystem  Microsoft Windows 7 Professional |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2  66053
               3433281             18371       17072          828              17616              142090240        28740
               8         17481728          1072       46                      185                  51
       232                      240                 9800               0                                   24
11076071      117727232    6.1.7601        28708864        6                    820
```

Buried in that mess is the `CreationDate` field (value `20160709170336.990827-420`) which is what you want.  The `-420` appears to be a timezone offset in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a class that is able to run Windows command to query the Windows logs. This can be done in this fashion:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {
        rt.exec("Your command");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Using wmic you'll be able to find the start time you want as stated above.

Unfortunately the sc won't be able to provide you with this kind of information. Another way (not sure if it would work though) is to query the window's event viewer for the logged event of a service starting (I think it's eventId is 902). After getting the information you can parse the string to find information regarding the service you're interested.

One word of warning though. If you're planning to deploy your app on older Windows installation be careful as old Windows installations (XP etc. etc.) may not always contain a valid WMIC installation, meaning that the command would not be available.